# Excel: if value is in column then return a different value

Tags: microsoft-excel

See screenshot below. I have data in columns A and B.  Column D are the values (taken from A2:B5) I am interested in. In Column E I want to know if the Column D values are Limit or Ultimate.  I.e. I want to search A2:B5 for a value in Column D (17, for example), and I want to the output to be Limit or Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried so far? Did you get as far as an IF and a pair of MATCH functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CHOOSE and AGGREGATE:

```
=CHOOSE(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($A$2:$B$5)/($A$2:$B$5=D2),1),2),"Limit","Ultimate","Neither")
```

The aggregate will return the column number `1` or `2` to the Choose which will then return the correct value depending on what the AGGREGATE returned.

Another is to use two MATCH in nested IFS:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"Limit",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,B:B,0)),"Ultimate","Neither))
```

With two columns the IF will be better as it will be quicker.  If one gets more then the first will be easier to maintain.

Comment: Scott, thanks much for the quick help.  Just what I needed and works great.

Comment: @StephanNelle please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.